# Error creating database while running container with docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I am trying to create a container with `docker-compose` so I ran `docker-compose up` on the following compose file:

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_USER: admin 
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: joesam007#
        MYSQL_DATABASE: Woodcore-test
```

After pulling and building the image, while trying to create the db, the error response shows thus:

```
Creating microservice-task_mysql_1 ... 
Creating microservice-task_mysql_1 ... error

ERROR: for microservice-task_mysql_1  Cannot start service mysql: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint microservice-task_mysql_1 (3f2a9ad024c6e586a9c7f089a388cecf7decbf7870106b5b34e5a21e88b415a3): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
```

I'd like to know how to handle this issue and create the db successfully. Please help, thanks.

Comment: `listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use`: make sure you don't have another service or app running on this port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running an existing MySQL Database on your host port 3306.
You can confirm via the following command:

```
Windows: netstat -a | findstr :3306
Linux: netstat -a | grep :3306
```

If you don't want to stop that Database/Service consuming that port, you can always change the host port which it binds to by updating your docker-compose config file to:

```
- "3307:3306"
```

This will then let you connect to the containers database on port 3307 from the host machine.

Comment: Awesome. It worked when I changed the host port. But I still have issues running my microservice, can I show you that as well?

Comment: Sure, might be best to create a new question unless it is a similar error?